# kernprof.py not working on windows for line profiling

Tags: python, profiling

I have a program named `getGraphs2.py` on which I want to do line profiling.

I have even decorated the the function I want to profile with `@profile`.

I enter this in the command line:

```
kernprof.py -l -b -v getGraphs2.py
```

This is the result that I get always:

```
Usage: kernprof.py [-s setupfile] [-o output_file_path] scriptfile [arg] ...
```

I even checked the source of `kernprof.py`:

```
## at line 174
    if not sys.argv[1:]:    ## Always an empty array
        parser.print_usage()
        sys.exit(2)
```

This is the part of the code due to which I always get this result. `sys.argv[1:]` is always an empty array.

Am I entering the command the wrong way ?

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this exact same issue this morning. Apparently our registry keys are off, and not passing arguments along. The instructions here fixed it for me. http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/12/14/problem-passing-arguments-to-python-scripts-on-windows/.

The relevant bit is (assuming your Python executable is at `C:\Python26\python26.exe`) to set the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command` to `"C:\Python26\python26.exe" "%1" %*`.

Comment: Could you add the actual fix to your answer? Not the whole post, just the relevant point. The link to the reference is also helpful, but it could break at some point in the future.